# Magento 2 : Are there any APIs to import massive external data (products) from a third-party application into Magento2 database programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product, api

Are there Magento2 API to import massive external data (products) from a third-party application into Magento2 database programmatically using API?

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends in which format the third party is supplying information but if you can read it programatically a pass parameters to API, then create product API can help you.

You can find all the info about API here ;

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Just search for **catalogProductRepositoryV1** and **POST /V1/products** is the API you need.

You can learn how to call APIs and their authentication in magento here -

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/bk-rest.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting project which provides import by API https://github.com/business-factory/roi-hunter-easy-magento2-plugin